# MySQL 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

Could you suggest why CHARGEITEM, INVOICE and PAYMENT might be failing? What am I missing here?

I checked these:

- All PKs and FKs are BIGINT columns
- I made them nullable columns
- Removed the constraint names (thinking they might be clashing)
- Added ON DELETE RESTRICT
- I also checked that all of them are INNODB.

Here is the full script (tables 6, 8 and 9 are failing):

```
CREATE TABLE `BUILDING` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `ROOM` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BUILDINGID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLOORNUM` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOORNUM` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `BUILDINGID` (`BUILDINGID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`BUILDINGID`) REFERENCES `BUILDING` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `BOOKING` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ENTRYDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTCONTACT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTADDRESS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTIDTYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTIDNUM` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTPASSPORTNUM` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `BOOKINGROOM` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BOOKINGID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROOMID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `BOOKINGID` (`BOOKINGID`),
  KEY `ROOMID` (`ROOMID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`BOOKINGID`) REFERENCES `BOOKING` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`ROOMID`) REFERENCES `ROOM` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `CHARGE` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CHARGEGROUP` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARGECODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNIT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITRATE` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `CHARGEITEM` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BOOKINGID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROOMID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARGEID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTRYSTAFFID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTRYDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUEDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNIT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITRATE` double NOT NULL,
  `UNITS` double NOT NULL,
  `AMOUNT` double NOT NULL,
  `NOTES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INVOICEID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `INVOICEID` (`INVOICEID`),
  KEY `ROOMID` (`ROOMID`),
  KEY `BOOKINGID` (`BOOKINGID`),
  KEY `CHARGEID` (`CHARGEID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`INVOICEID`) REFERENCES `INVOICE` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`ROOMID`) REFERENCES `ROOM` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`BOOKINGID`) REFERENCES `BOOKING` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`CHARGEID`) REFERENCES `CHARGE` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `DROPDOWNENTRY` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MODULE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POSITION` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `KEY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `INVOICE` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BOOKINGID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ENTRYSTAFFID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTRYDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTHSTAFFID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTHDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `NETAMOUNT` double NOT NULL,
  `TAX1` double NOT NULL,
  `TAX2` double NOT NULL,
  `TAX3` double NOT NULL,
  `TOTALTAX` double NOT NULL,
  `TOTALINCLTAX` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `BOOKINGID` (`BOOKINGID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`BOOKINGID`) REFERENCES `BOOKING` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `PAYMENT` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `INVOICEID` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AMOUNTPAID` double NOT NULL,
  `PAYMODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTRYDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUEDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `REALISATIONDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `BANKCODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSTRUMENTNUM` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POSCODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REALISATIONSTATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `INVOICEID` (`INVOICEID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`INVOICEID`) REFERENCES `INVOICE` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `RESERVATION` (
  `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ENTRYDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `FROMDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `TODATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMROOMS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `GUESTNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTCONTACT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUESTADDRESS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Try making then *non-nullable*

Comment: Try adding the foreign keys after all the tables are created

Comment: @Psi Atleast a few of them need to be nullable as per my use case. For example charges which have not been grouped would not have invoice id

Comment: @DanIonescu Sure..  I'll try it out now. Although I don't understand why it wouldn't work within the create query.

Comment: `ON DELETE RESTRICT`: If there is a record in that table that does not point to an existing primary key, the constraint creation will fail

Comment: It would work because you are trying to reference tables before they are created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- `INVOICES` doesnt exists when you are referring it in another table. Either define the table before referring or define constraints after all the tables are created.
- in `INVOICES` table, you are defining data type varchar(255) but in foreign key, it refers to a bigint column - won't work.

  In `INVOICES` table,

  ```
  `BOOKINGID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ```

  change it to:

  ```
  `BOOKINGID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ```

Fixed both here -

http://rextester.com/JAZOUD38011

Comment: Oh! I missed that. I changed the data types of serveral columns!

Comment: Very poor error messages from MySQL. Ate up so much time to get a few FK columns data types changed :(

Comment: @Teddy - You should execute it one by one. That way you will know where exactly the error occured.

Comment: I get it. I should do it one by one. But, if MySQL had just mentioned the column name in the error message...... Oh well, I'll keep wishing

Comment: @Teddy - Yes sometimes the error messages are not as helpful as they could be. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Databases do not support *forward* foreign key references.  In `CHARGEITEM` for instance you have:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`INVOICEID`) REFERENCES `INVOICE` (`ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
```

However, the `INVOICE` table is created *after* `CHARGEITEM`.  Hence, this will fail, and so on.

Two options:

- Line up your tables so they are created before they are referenced.  Note that this is not always possible, because your data model can have circular references.
- Define all the tables first and then define all the foreign key references using `alter table add constraint`.

Comment: In the case of wrong order, the script would miss some tables in the first run. But, if I run the same script again and again, the missing tables should get created. Also, even if I execute that create statement separately it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here:

`ON DELETE RESTRICT`: If there is a record in that table that does not point to an existing primary key, the constraint creation will fail. That includes `null`-values.

After you said you need nullable values there, it won't work. Either set your constraint to `ON RESTRICT SET NULL` or make the fields `NOT NULL`.

Comment: For your first point, its a fresh schema. All tables are fresh without any data in them! I'm not sure I understand the second one...

Comment: I will look into on restrict set null

Comment: Also check the other answer about forward declaration.